AWS Amplify, github, nodejs integration with Python-shell, module not found issue
Basically, I have an Amplify app that uses NodeJS and github. I'm currently trying to have App.js (the file that has the website code for Amplify's frontend) run a python script using nodeJS's python-shell feature.
When I attempt to deploy the github branch that I update through VScode CLI commands I get the following error in the Amplify deployment build:

2024-08-20T22:37:23.029Z [INFO]: Failed to compile.
2024-08-20T22:37:23.033Z [INFO]: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/codebuild/output/src510161372/src/fabmansync/node_modules/python-shell'
2024-08-20T22:37:23.135Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2024-08-20T22:37:23.136Z [ERROR]: !!! Error: Command failed with exit code 1.

I've googled around a lot and I'm afraid it may be that child-process can't be run from browser, if this is the case or there's some sort of work around please do let me know. Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^5.1.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@fontsource/barlow-condensed": "^4.5.0",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.34",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/node": "^22.4.1",
    "assert": "^2.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.21",
    "boto3": "^0.0.1",
    "botocore": "^0.0.1",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "fontsource-barlow-condensed": "^4.0.0",
    "fontsource-roboto": "^4.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "imask": "^6.2.2",
    "markdown-to-jsx": "^7.1.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "python-shell": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "schema-utils": "^4.0.0",
    "secrets": "^1.1.5",
    "stream": "^0.0.3",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}


I'm fairly new to all this stuff so any help would be appreciated. Also I am not using webpack at all as I'm completely unfamiliar with it so "browser: child_process: false" will not work I've tried.
I've also tried npm install child_process plenty of times. Plus quite a bit of other things that I just can't remember. Also I know that I could just use Lambda and dynamoDB to run the python code and access it's contents but for my situation I'm pretty sure that would be really inefficient and too slow. Thanks for any help you can offer.
